# How can I make pandas DataFrame.transform() call faster?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a big pandas data frame as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

length = 10000000000
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'group': [random.choice(range(1, (length/5))) for _ in range(length)],
        'val': np.random.rand(length)
        })
```

Now I'd like to calculate the distances between elements within a group.

```
df['distance'] = df.groupby('group').transform(
        lambda x: np.concatenate([np.diff(x.index), np.array([np.nan])]))
```

How can I make this operation faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
length = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'group': [random.choice(range(1, int(length/5))) for _ in range(length)],
        'val': np.random.rand(length)
        })

#print (df)
```

---

```
In [317]: %timeit df['distance'] = df.groupby('group').transform(lambda x: np.concatenate([np.diff(x.index), np.array([np.nan])]))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.74 s per loop

In [318]: %timeit df['distance1'] = pd.Series(df.index).groupby(df['group']).diff(-1).abs()
1 loop, best of 3: 200 ms per loop

In [319]: %timeit df['distance2'] = df.reset_index().groupby('group')['index'].diff(-1).abs()
1 loop, best of 3: 201 ms per loop
```

Comment: I appreciate your help!

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Can I wait for other answers for a short time? I don't think there would be a better solution, but I would like to compare various solutions. If there is no other answer for a couple of hours, I will accept your answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @Han - Yes, sure, no problem.